# How can I iterate through a folder and move/copy every Nth item

Tags: folders, file, sort

I want to make a time lapse from a folder of images, but there are too many and the time lapse progresses to slowly.  How do I select, for example, every 10th item, and either copy or move the items into a separate folder?

Comment: @njboot, Nice command however it fails if there are spaces in the file names.

Comment: You may want to comment directly on njboot's answer. I am not sure this will work, try putting double or single quotes around `$file` in the command so the middle part looks like `do echo mv "$file" /DEST/DIR` or `do echo mv '$file' /DEST/DIR` and possibly escape the quotes but I don't think you'll need to: `do echo mv \"$file\" /DEST/DIR`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The quickest way is to use `bash` and `awk` syntax in your **Terminal.app**

```
for file in `find /SOURCE/DIR -type f | awk 'NR %10 == 0'`; do echo mv $file /DEST/DIR ; done
```

---

`for` statement introduces the `bash loop`, to iterate through a set of data where `file` is the variable.

`find` parses the `/SOURCE/DIR` for that which is specified.

`|` acts as a pipe, passing stout from `find` back to stdin

`awk` interprets stdin and prints only lines meeting the conditions specified by `'NR %10 == 0’`

- `NR` is an `awk built-in variable` that specifies the record/line number to be evaluated.
- `%` is a `numerical operator` telling awk that the following character(s) must be treated as such.
- `==` is relational operator for `must be equal to..`
- `0` is the binary expression for `TRUE`

So, that’s all fancy for  **"find every 10th file that exists in this directory and output it**;

- `do` introduces the action to perform on the output.
- `echo` is used to double check the command, the results of which will be printed to stout. If all looks well, remove it and perform the action (`mv`, `cp`)
- `mv` is a built in bash command to take one file and move(or rename it).
- `cp` is another built in bash command to mv one file from one dir. to another while preserving the original. You can directly substitute `cp` for `mv` if you wish to preserve the contents of the original directory.
- `$file` references the `file` variable that has now been defined.

So, that’s all fancy for **tell me what happens when I…(`echo`) “`move` (or, `copy`) all the files specified by the previous parameters to this other directory;”**

- `done`

**That’s all fancy for telling bash to terminate the loop since you’re done :)**